# Quartz StartAt time proper DateTime format?

Tags: c#, datetime, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a time given as a string (ex: `timeString = "2:00 PM"`) and would like to parse a `DateTime` from it to pass to my CronTrigger's `.StartAt()` in Quartz. However, `DateTime.Parse(timeString)` gives me `7/15/2014 2:00:00 PM`, which I believe is the incorrect format for `.StartAt()`, since I get a `FormatException`. I have also tried `DateTime.Parse(timeString).ToUniversalTime()`, `DateTimeOffset.Parse(timeString)`, and `DateTimeOffset.Parse(timeString).ToUniversalTime()` and got the same error.

Looking online, I'm not sure what the correct format is.

Here is the relevant code. All the variables (`triggerName`, `groupName`, etc) are passed into the function correctly.

```
return TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity(triggerName, groupName)
    .StartAt(DateTime.Parse(startString))
    .WithCronSchedule(cronSchedule)
    .Build();
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the exception you get? It would be useful to know whether it's within `DateTime.Parse`, or whether it's a Quartz issue.

Comment: I get the following popup in Visual Studio, highlighting the code I included in the question: "FormatException was unhandled. An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Quartz.dll. Additional information: Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented".

Comment: If it helps, the `cronSchedule` string reads `0 0/1 * ? * MON-FRI`, so it does not attempt to specify both day-of-week and day-of-month. I am fairly sure the problem is the `.StartAt()` part.

Answer (score 1):

The TriggerBuilder expects a DateTimeOffset (from the [TriggerBuilder.cs](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/TriggerBuilder.cs) file):

```
 public TriggerBuilder StartAt(DateTimeOffset startTimeUtc)
 {
     startTime = startTimeUtc;
     return this;
 }
```

Take a look at the DateTimeOffset Parse method's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351654(v=vs.110).aspx) for examples of the format it expects for dates and times.

Finally, you should always pass times to Quartz.Net in UTC as this is what it expects, so convert accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use cron notation with Quartz. If you plan on using this format for your time you can generate a cron expression this way :

```
String.Format("0 {0} {1} * *", (timeString[2]+timeString[3]), timeString[0]);
```

Now you will have to work with 24 hours format for this to work. I recommend that you change the way you format your time in your program, but you can detect if it's p.M with your format this way :

```
if(timeString.Split(' ')[1] == "PM")
```